# Cannot recognize modal by appium

Tags: react-native, appium, react-native-ios, appium-ios

I have an application created by react-native which contains a modal raise from bottom. Now I'm tring to use appium to automate the application and in android it works fine. While in iOS, when I try to use appium inspector on the modal, it just get penetrated and return control below.

```
        <Modal style={styles.bottomModal} isVisible={btmModal} backdropOpacity={0.3} onBackdropPress={this._closeBtmModal}>
          <View style={styles.ways}>
            <TouchableOpacity accessibilityLabel={IDS.MANUAL_NAV_CAMERA} testID={IDS.MANUAL_NAV_CAMERA} style={styles.line} onPress={() => this._navCamera()}>
              <Image style={styles.scan} source={require('../../../resources/images/scan.png')} /><Text style={styles.lineTxt}>扫码绑定</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={IDS.MANUAL_ADD_TEXT} testid={IDS.MANUAL_ADD_TEXT} style={styles.line} onPress={this._navManualBindMfa}>
              <Text style={styles.lineTxt}>手动输入</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={IDS.MANUAL_ADD_MODAL_CANCEL} testId={IDS.MANUAL_ADD_MODAL_CANCEL} style={[styles.line, styles.cancelline]} onPress={this._closeBtmModal}>
              <Text style={styles.cancelTxt}>取消</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

Try to get appium inspector working against this modal. Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing same kind of problem, can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible strategies to try:

1. "setting accessible={false} on outer most layer makes child views accessible."

See https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6517#issuecomment-298037046

2. If your modal has a transparent background the components behind may will still be marked as visible. I use an environment variable set in the build for testing with appium which removes the transparency option. This does mean that the build being tested is not identical to the normal build

Comment: Pretty sketchy hack :D

Comment: First of suggested options worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

- React-Native 0.63
- Desktop Appium 1.22.0
- Appium Inspector 2022.1.2

In our project the obstacle was the element `Pressable`. Setting property `accessible={false}` to it fixed an ability for Appium to find elements on **modal windows** as well. `<TouchableOpacity  accessible={false}>` also plays role for finding elements on **screens**.

I have to ***highlight*** that Appium Inspector's screenshot view still won't recognize elements, but its searching functionality ('id' for iOS) finds them.

Answer (score 0):

Up until now, I was under the impression that if Appium Inspector does not render a component then it means it does not see it, therefore I won't be able to use it in tests.

As it turns out, its searching engine can still find such a component, and therefore we can use it in tests, although sometimes it requires adding additional props to certain components, like `accessible={false}` or a `testID` to a parent component.